# Как сделать проверку на снятие роли пользователю

Tags: python, discord.py

````
@client.event
async def on_member_update(remove_roles):
    await ctx.channel.send(f'Тест')```
Как сделать проверку на снятие роли участнику. После снятия роли бот отправлял сообщение в чат к примеру: **Пользователю {members.mention} снята роль {role.mentions}
К примеру есть несколько ролей на которые он будет трегерриться
````

```
vagos_zam = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 942397028804206615)
ballas_zam = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 942397028804206617)
aztec_zam = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 942397028804206616)
rifa_zam = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, id = 942397028804206614)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во первых

```
discord.on_member_update(before, after)
```

принимает параметры before & after
Во вторых

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    a = ['role1','role2','role3'] # сюда пихаем имена ваших ролей
    if len(before.roles) < len(after.roles):
        for i in after.roles:
            if not i in before.roles:
                print(type(i.name))
                if i.name in a:
                    print(f"К участнику {before.display_name} добавлена роль {i}")
                    #Ваше действие
    elif len(before.roles) > len(after.roles):
        for i in before.roles:
            if not i in after.roles:
                if i.name in a:
                    print(f"У участника {before.display_name} снята роль {i}")
                    #ваше действие
```

Answer (score 0):

Также, чтобы отправить сообщение в определенный канал используйте

```
bot.get_channel(id).send("Ваше сообщение")
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы участника которому снималась роль упоминало

Comment: before & after- class member, поэтому чтобы уоминуть используйте after.mention